# How to apply a free-form input Function using InputField

Tags: manipulate, inputfield, free-form-input

I am trying to take a free-form input `Function` to create a list using `NestList`.

```
  Manipulate[list2 = NestList[f, .8, 10], {f, (1/3) x^3, InputField[_, String]}, 
     ControlType -> InputField]
```

Which generates this output:

> {0.8, ((x^3)/3)[0.8], ((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[0.8]], ((x^3)/
>     3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[0.8]]], ((x^3)/
>     3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[0.8]]]], ((x^3)/
>     3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[0.8]]]]], ((x^3)/
>     3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[0.8]]]]]], ((
>     x^3)/3)[((x^3)/
>      3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[0.8]]]]]]], ((
>     x^3)/3)[((x^3)/
>      3)[((x^3)/
>       3)[((x^3)/
>        3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[0.8]]]]]]]], ((x^3)/
>     3)[((x^3)/
>      3)[((x^3)/
>       3)[((x^3)/
>        3)[((x^3)/
>         3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[0.8]]]]]]]]], ((x^3)/
>     3)[((x^3)/
>      3)[((x^3)/
>       3)[((x^3)/
>        3)[((x^3)/
>         3)[((x^3)/
>          3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[((x^3)/3)[0.8]]]]]]]]]]}

I would like to have a numeric output.

Comment: The problem is in function definition, `x` does not mean anything in this form. Try `(1/3) #^3 &`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have mentioned in comment the problem is that `(1/3)x^3` is not a proper function definition. Applying this to Your starting value will give You, as one can expect:

```
(* => (1/3)x^3 [.8]*)
```

Natural way is to use pure function form for it: `(1/3)#^3&`.

```
Manipulate[
 list2 = NestList[f, .8, 10], 
 {f, (1/3) #^3 &, InputField[_]}, ControlType -> InputField]
```

[image]

But it does not look good in `InputField`, it is also not convenient to type. The following solution will fix that:

```
Manipulate[
 list2 = NestList[f /. x -> # &, .8, 10],
 {f, (1/3) x^3, InputField[_]}, ControlType -> InputField]
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if the user enters `42 + u^3`? :P

Comment: @m_goldberg well, nothing special, I;m not sure what do you mean :P