# Fold Dynamic Function

Tags: functions, dynamic, scoping

I'm making on a demo working with differential equations as functions of two variables (x and y). The demo will have to Fold the differential equation with an initial y-value and a series of x-values. Here's a simple code for the demo. The output should be a list on new y-values.

```
DynamicModule[{dydx = Null}, 
Deploy@
Panel@
Grid@
Transpose@
{{"Differential equation: (dy/dx)=", 
   "List of Slopes:"},
  {InputField[Dynamic[dydx]], 
   InputField[Dynamic[FoldList[dydx, 1, {0, 1, 2, 3}]]]}}]
```

The code doesn't work because dydx cannot be applied as a function in FoldList. "dydx" needs to be defined as a function f[y_,x_]. However, I'm not sure how to dynamically change a function using InputField.

```
f[y_,x_]= dydx
FoldList[f,1,{0,1,2,3}]
```

I'd like to have this as part of the Dynamic Module. Users would be able to input a function then receive a list of new y values.
Any advice?

Comment: Hi, you may be interested in [this topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26983/5478). Which may be even considered  duplicate.

Comment: So, are you or I've missed the point?

Comment: Wow, thanks for checking back in! That topic is exactly what I needed.