# How use TraditionalForm input in InputField?

Tags: manipulate, inputfield, traditional-form

Inside a `Manipulate`, I'd like one of the controls to be an `InputField` and to allow the input entered to be in traditional form. Is this possible?

For example, in the output from

```
  Manipulate[func /. x -> val,
     {{val, 0, "x"}}, {{func, x, "f(x)"}},
     ControlType -> InputField]
```

I'd like to be able to type, say, `cos(x)` in the second input field and have it interpreted, of course, as `Cos[x]`.

Comment: related [26983](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26983/5478)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Manipulate[ToExpression[func, TraditionalForm] /. x -> val, {{val, Pi, "x"}, InputField},
 {{func, "", "f(x)"}, InputField[##, String] &}]
```

[image]

Comment: Should I be able to surmise such an answer from the documentation?

Comment: That's an interesting mathematical value, resulting from $\sin(\pi/5) = \sqrt{(5-\sqrt{5})/8}$.

Comment: @murray, thank you for the Accept. Re documentation, the key piece is from [TraditionalForm >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TraditionalForm.html). We can get the _uninteresting_ values using `Manipulate[N@ToExpression[func, ...]`  or  `Manipulate[1. ToExpression[func, ...]`:)

Comment: The `ToExpression[..., TraditionalForm]` part I already knew about. What I did *not* know was the legality of a control of type `{{expr, default, "label"}, InputField[#, String]&}`. So applying such a `ToExpression` construct to the input read didn't occur to me. Of course this *did* appear in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26983/how-to-apply-a-free-form-input-function-using-inputfield?rq=1.

Comment: murray,  `InputField[##, String, options]&` is a special case of the general syntax for Manipulate controls `{{u, init,label}, controlfunction[##, options]&}`.  A reference is in [Advanced Manipulate Functionality >> Custom Control Appearances](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html).

Comment: @kgular: Yep, the general syntax is indicated in the reference you cite, although it is a bit hard to spot and dig out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer uses a [`String`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String) type [`InputField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField), so that you can't enter 2D input. The following [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate) version allows 2D input:

```
Manipulate[
    ToExpression[func, TraditionalForm] /. {Null->"", x->val},
    {{val,Pi,"x"}, InputField},
    {{func, Null, "f(x)"}, TraditionalForm@InputField[Dynamic[func],Boxes]&}
]
```

Here is an animation:

[image]